# Loading Database tables in classes

Tags: php, mysql

Is it a good practice to load an entire table from a database into a class?

for example a user class? Adding all the information of users in a class?

Comment: Probably not.  You should use database operations to work with data stored in a database.

Comment: PHP has limited memory, so loading large volumes of data into that memory is going to be an overhead and only justifiable if you gain some real tangible benefit to outweight that cost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your table has a few data it will be fine to get all the information. 
*e.g. if user table has only 3 users; student, tutor and admin along with their ids it is ok to get all the data.*

But if the table has a large amount of data it is not a good practice to load whole table. Therefore you can use the operations such as `LIMIT` to query limited number of rows.

LIMIT example:

```
SELECT * FROM `my_table` LIMIT 0, 5
```

(This will display the first 5 results from 'my_table'.)

For **pagination** following will be useful:

1. totalRows = the total number of rows in DB. (can be taken using `COUNT` in sql)
2. itemsPerPage = define how many items you want to show in a single page
3. numberOfPages = totalRows/ itemsPerPage (numberOfPages is useful to
   display the page numbers in the page).
4. startingItem = (pageNumber - 1) * itemsPerPage
5. SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT startingItem, itemsPerPage

So basically you will need to **pass the pageNumber to a function** (when user clicks on a page) in order to **retrieve limited number of rows**.

Comment: I need to limit the number of calls to the database as much as possible, is there anyway I can do this?

Comment: Yes possible. You can control the number of calls and the number of rows you need to retrieve per call. 
Pagination is an example for this. You can retrieve data according to the number of pages you need or according to the number of items you need per page.

Comment: So do you want limit the number of calls to do pagination? If so I can extend the answer a bit accordingly

Comment: This is the method you can use. '
1. totalRows = the total number of rows in DB. 2. numberOfPages=totalRows/ itemsPerPage (numberOfPages is useful to display the page numbers in the page). 3.startingItem = (pageNumber - 1) * itemsPerPage 4. SELECT * FROM `my_table` LIMIT startingItem, itemsPerPage **So basically you will need to pass the pageNumber to a function (when user clicks on a page) in order to retrieve limited number of rows.**

Comment: Could you add this to your answer? Just for other people, so it's better structured :)